# module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2.estimator' has no attribute 'inputs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow version 2.0.0-beta1. While calling

```
tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn
```

it is giving me an error.

```
module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2.estimator' has no attribute 'inputs'
```

In order to identify the problem I tried with

```
tf.estimator.inputs
```

which gave me the following error

```
module 'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v2.estimator' has no attribute 'inputs'
```

I have tried reinstalling tensorflow on my local machine and also on Google Colab but that doesn't seem to work. Is there any change in this function in newer version of tensorflow as compared to previous version of tensorflow i.e. (tf version 1.x)

Comment: The interface seems to have been removed from TensorFlow 2.x (see [`tf.estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/estimator)). You can still access it through [`tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/inputs), but I guess you are supposed to use [`tf.data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/data) instead (if not [`tf.keras`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras) models).

Answer (score 9):

In `Tensorflow V1` While reading input from Pandas DataFrames for `tf.estimator` we used this command: `tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn`. But now due to API changes, we will have to replace that command with this one: `tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn`. Here we are getting the same command from the Version1 into Version2 of Tensorflow.

Answer (score 2):

```
tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn
```

Comment: Make sure to explain your code. Why does this work and what's different about it, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's a great answer or explanation given for the problem by Tensor flow versions while working with TensorFlow use cases even I have faced the same issue with the inputs but after replacing the function with this as

```
input_fun=tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,batch_size=100,num_epochs=None,shuffle=True)
```

the problem got resolved.
have a great day!
Thank you!
Happy Friendship Day to all IT professionals!

Regards,
Kalyani Reddy
Data Scientist

Comment: Please review your post for readability.